# Kotlin Extension Functions suddenly require api level 24

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I just noticed this lint error:

> Call requires API Level 24 (current min is 19) java.util.map#foreach

when I use the extension function forEach on a MutableMap in Kotlin.
This didn't happen when I wrote the line, but its there now.
And I'm not seeing this error on my other machine.

Comment: Try invalidate cache and run `gradle clean` since your other machine isn't getting that error. Also check Naetmul's anwser below.

Comment: Whilst Naetmul's answer seems to be the cause of your issue, I'm currently seeing a lot of these warnings for no reason in AS3.0 anyway, even in things like `Bundle#putBoolean`. Linting seems a bit broken currently.

Comment: In case you recently pass by here after migrating to Kotlin 1.5.0, there is a Lint bug in AGP 4.1, causing a similar issues. Please refer to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185418482 for details.
TL;DR you need to update to AGP 4.2.0 first

Comment: Not resolved to this date even with the latest version of AGP. Thanks a lot Konsumierer for the issuetracker link, will follow this closely.

Comment: This issue reappears in Kotlin 1.9.x, for people coming here due to that: the answers below still work

Answer (score 84, accepted):

What you are using is not `kotlin.collections.MutableMap.forEach`.

What you are using seems to be `Map.forEach` in Java 8.

Refer to this article:
http://blog.danlew.net/2017/03/16/kotlin-puzzler-whose-line-is-it-anyways/

This seems to be a common mistake.

Java 8 is well-supported from Android API level 24.

For short, do not use `forEach` like `map.forEach { t, u -> Log.i("tag", t + u) }` (this is using Java 8 API, which does not work for Android API level <= 23).
Use it like `map.forEach { (t, u) -> Log.i("tag", t + u) }` (this is using Kotlin API).
(Not two parameters. Just one parameter that is a pair.)

Comment: this solved it for me. The same thing is happening for replace() on MutableMap, so im guessing this is the same cause

Comment: double accepted answer. this allows me to use forEach on kotlin.

Comment: The file is entirely written in Kotlin, and it still gives this error.  There's no way to be using Java 8 from Kotlin.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Typically you're using Kotlin with some Java libraries, so the Java version of those libraries may matter. The two arg version of j.u.Map.forEach is from Java 8 onwards, i.e., Android API 24 onwards.

Comment: @Naetmul what is the relation between java language features and android api levels?

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB Android API Level <= 23: Java 7, Android API Level >= 24: Subset of Java 8, https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html It seems that Google does not try to include Java 9 language features to Android. Just use Kotlin instead.

Comment: BTW, I found the same issue reappeared after the kotlin 1.5.x upgrade. It was a problem that is already fixed in 4.2: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185418482

Comment: I am using the single argument version and this problem just appeared for me. ref `event.attributes?.forEach { (key, value) ->
          if (key != null && value != null) {
            put(key, value)
          }
        }`

Comment: I have like 30 places where I get this error and can't manage to make it work with this solution. I have to use import kotlin.collections.forEach as kForEach and then use kForEach instead of forEach

Answer (score 11):

This also happens in a list even tho I'm using I need to use:

```
list.iterator().forEach {}
```

the key is use `iterator()` before forEach.

Comment: This solved it for me.  I am using the single argument version as mentioned in another answer (ref. `event.attributes?.forEach { (key, value) ->           if (key != null && value != null) {             put(key, value)           }         }`).

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this because the map a dependency provided was a Java 8 map, so the `forEach` was linted as the Java 8 version, no matter how I grouped my parameters in the lambda signature (`one, two ->` vs `(one, two) ->`). Best solution I could find was using an explicit import with an alias (`import kotlin.collections.forEach as kForEach`). The alias keeps optimize imports from removing the explicit import.

Answer (score -3):

Map.forEach is supported in Java 8 and its support in Android started from API 24

Comment: This is for Kotlin