# Android API version checking not happening while Kotlin build

Tags: android, kotlin

How to make Kotlin give API level errors at time of coding, instead of at runtime.

App Gradle file:

```
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 26
```

Kotlin Code:

```
//initialisation
var data = getSomedata() //the returned type is Map<String, String>
data.getOrDefault("SomeKey","DefaultValue")
```

Issue:

Code compiles fine and also able to create signed APK. But when the APK is executed on devices with API 22(Android 5) following error is thrown.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Expected beheviour:

If I call the function in java file, lint checking will give following error even before compiling.

> Call requires API level 24 (current min is 19): java.util.Map#getOrDefault

**CHECKED DUPLICATE**

Already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751469/kotlin-extension-functions-suddenly-require-api-level-24). It is providing reason for the behavior which i have already derived. I need the resolution or work around. As of now I am not sure which all methods would not work at runtime, and users would be reporting those errors which IDE or compiler should have reported.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751469/kotlin-extension-functions-suddenly-require-api-level-24

Answer (score 3):

Quite likely this will have to be done by Android Studio/Kotlin team.

Method `kotlin.Map.getOrDefault()` in theory is valid on any Android API, however its internal implementation (delegating call to `java.util.HashMap.getOrDefault()`) is valid only on JDK 1.8+.

Moreover method `kotlin.Map.getOrDefault()` in its docs is marked as `@since JDK 1.8`. I suppose we need to wait some time for IDE team to implement a warning for methods marked in docs as `@since XXX`

You can also upvote or comment issues on Kotlin's YouTrack

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20358

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21503