# Lint considers Kotlin MutableMap.forEach() as java.util.Map.forEach()

Tags: java, android, collections, kotlin

I am using Kotlin's MutableMap in my Android project. And trying to do some action per item. So here is my code.

```
private val uris: MutableMap<String, Uri> = mutableMapOf()
// ... Fill the items here ...
uris.forEach {
    val ref = FirebaseFirestore.getInstanse().reference
    uploadFile(ref, it.value)
}
```

Everything just works fine at runtime, but my CI build fails with below lint error:

```
MyActivity.kt:142: Error: Call requires API level 24 (current min is 16): java.util.Map#forEach [NewApi]
              uris.forEach {
                   ~~~~~~~
```

I know we can't use JDK-8's Map for Android projects until the min sdk is 24. But why lint is considering it as JDK-8's Map?

For further information I tried getting the Java code from Kotlin Bytecode option in AS and found that forEach is replaced with while loop and iterator as expected.

So what could be reason and how to solve this? Any lead will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the Kotlin standard library in your dependencies?

Comment: In the code sample map's name is `uris`, while in the error message it's `shopIcons`. Are you sure you're looking in the right place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin Extension Functions suddenly require api level 24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751469/kotlin-extension-functions-suddenly-require-api-level-24)

Comment: @AlexFilatov, thats my mistake. It was a copy paste problem. Fixed it now.

Comment: Can it be a error in the Link check?

Comment: Lint __should__ resolve the method used the same way as the IDE's editor and the compiler does though. @ChandraSekhar if you navigate to the declaration of the `forEach` you're using, does it go to the Kotlin one as it should?

Comment: @zsmb13, yes it goes to kotlin one. Not to the Java one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two overloaded `foreach`s on `Map`:

Kotlin one:

```
uris.forEach { (key, value) -> // Do some Action }
```

Java8 one:

```
uris.forEach { key, value -> // Do some Action }
```

Confusing, isn't it?

Comment: I am using uris.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<K, V>) -> Unit) one

Comment: Okay, so what now? I'm using data.forEach { /* Do something with 'it' */ } and is complaining.

Comment: Wondering what those parentheses mean in the Kotlin variant? It's a destructuring declaration that breaks down a `Map.Entry<K, V>` instance into two separate variables. https://blog.danlew.net/2017/03/16/kotlin-puzzler-whose-line-is-it-anyways/

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an import problem. Maybe you have used **JDK 8's Map.forEach**.

You have to use **kotlin.collections.MutableMap.forEach**

You can also check this blog:

http://blog.danlew.net/2017/03/16/kotlin-puzzler-whose-line-is-it-anyways/

Comment: Looks interesting. But my import statements has none of those.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you use forEach from Kotlin?
Because there are two `forEach`, one from Kotlin with `Map.Entry` as an argument and one from Java with two arguments: key and value.
Please, show full version of your code. If you use forEach without arguments, it means that you use Kotlin one (you have `it` implicit argument).

If you use Kotlin forEach and still have this warning you should report this issue to [Android Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Comment: @ChandraSekhar You use Kotlin version of forEach, so it's lint bug. Suppress this warning in Lint and report an issue to Android tracker