# How to tell the compiler to use Kotlin extension function instead of Java 8 function for Android App

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-interop

I want to use function `MutableList<T>.replaceAll(transformation: (T) -> T)` in my Android project.

There is a very similar question: 
[Kotlin Extension Functions suddenly require api level 24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751469/kotlin-extension-functions-suddenly-require-api-level-24)

But is my case, I want to use the function `replaceAll` which has identical syntax with **Java 8** implementation. So, the question is: how to tell the compiler that I want to use the extension function from **Kotlin** standard library instead of **Java 8** function.

Comment: what does mean 'identical'? in Kotlin it uses java List.replaceAll method

Comment: Java method uses 'UnaryOperator<E> operator' which is identical to 'transformation: (T) -> T' by SAM conversion.

Comment: I do not know why but it looks like `fun <T> MutableList<T>.replaceAll(transformation: (T) -> T)` is only available in [Kotlin Native](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/replace-all.html).