# .forEach for List - org.gradle.api.GradleException: - Error: Call requires API level 24 (current min is 22): java.lang.Iterable#forEach [NewApi]

Tags: android, gradle, lint

I have this code:

```
private val recipes: List<Recipe>,
...
recipes.forEach {
        recyclerItems.add(RecipeBinder(it, imageLoader, onRecipeClick))
}
```

And with check I have this error:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':androidclient:lintMyAppDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$3(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:268)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:184)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:173)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:411)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:398)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:391)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:377)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.


> Task :androidclient:lintMyAppDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':androidclient:lintMyAppDebug'.
> Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.

  Fix the issues identified by lint, or add the following to your build script to proceed with errors:
  ...
  android {
      lintOptions {
          abortOnError false
      }
  }
  ...
  The first 3 errors (out of 18) were:

Error: Call requires API level 24 (current min is 22): java.lang.Iterable#forEach [NewApi]
          recipes.forEach {
```

Version of Kotlin that I use: 1.6.10
and classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
How to fix it? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting this:

```
recipes.forEach {
    recyclerItems.add(RecipeBinder(it, imageLoader, onRecipeClick))
}
```

to this:

```
recipes.iterator().forEach {
    recyclerItems.add(RecipeBinder(it, imageLoader, onRecipeClick))
}
```

I think on using just **forEach**, the compiler thinks that it's the one from Java(https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer%3C?%20super%20E%3E)) which requires API 24.

(Not related to the question but I strongly recommend you to get the latest AGP version)

Comment: But what if I want to keep using .forEach for list? It is kotlin feature, not Java, why there is an error?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading the AGP Version to 7.0.4 though?

Comment: How to make compiler think, that I'm using exactly kotlin version? If I will update to AGP 7, I will have A LOT of another different issues, cause our code base is huge.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68897591/9520315 I am not sure if it works though.

Comment: I've seen already this answer, it's not my case :(

Answer (score -1):

You have two options

**1. Set your minimum SDK version to 24**
In your module level **build.gradle** , under defaultConfig, set minimumSdk to 21 and change the rest of your code to match it

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.somedomain.somepackage"
    **minSdkVersion 24**
    targetSdkVersion 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

**2.Use the Kotlin for in loop**

```
for(recipe in recipes){
recyclerItems.add(RecipeBinder(recipe, imageLoader, onRecipeClick))
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Go to your app's leve build.gradle file,
and change the minSdkVersion 22 -> minSdkVersion 24